# additivity of crossing number of composite knots

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Let $K_1 \# K_2$ denotes the connected sum of tow knots $K_1$ and $K_2$. The crossing number is the minimal number of crossings among all knot diagrams,  denoted by $c(K)$. It is conjectured that $c(K_1 \# K_2)=c(K_1) + c(K_2)$. Is this conjecture settled down or still open?   Is there any counterexample?.

Comment: «It i conjectured» by whom? Can you give references? That always make a question better!

Answer (score 3):

It's an open problem in general (there are no counterexamples, to my knowledge), but consider these partial results:

- $c(K_1 \# K_2) \le c(K_1) + c(K_2)$ for any two knots $K_1$, $K_2$.  To see this, suppose that you have diagrams for $K_1$ and $K_2$ with minimal number of crossings, say $n_1$ and $n_2$, respectively.  Their connect sum is a diagram for $K_1 \# K_2$ with $n_1 + n_2$ crossings, although this may not be minimal.
- Assuming that the knots are **alternating**, this is a theorem of Kauffman, Murasugi, and Thistlethwaite using knot polynomials.  (See [MR:0999974](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=999974).)
- There's a larger class of **adequate** knots that includes alternating knots for which the conjecture holds.
- The conjecture holds for **torus links**.  (See [arXiv:0303273](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303273))
- There's a bound in the other direction of the form $c(K_1 \# K_2) \ge \frac{1}{N} \bigl( c(K_1) + c(K_2) \bigr)$ for some constant $N$.  In one result, $N = 152$, but this can presumably be improved.  Of course, $N = 1$ would prove the conjecture in full generality.  (See [MR:2574742](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2574742).)

This question is as old as knot theory and Tait's conjectures.

Comment: Thank you Sammy for your answer.  But really I wonder why the diagram of connected sum of two knots with $n_1 + n_2$ crossings is not minimal.  I see that we can not apply any of Reidemeister moves to the resulting diagram.

Comment: I, too, would like to know why the connected sum of two minimal diagrams is minimal **if it's true.**  It is *an open problem* (nobody knows if it's true).

Comment: Regarding your comment "I see that we can not apply any of Reidemeister moves to the resulting diagram":  you might be overestimating your intuition about Reid. moves.  There are some mildly counterintuitive truths lurking in the web of Reid. moves.  For instance, there exist diagrams of a knot (of the same number of crossings) that can **only** be obtained, one from the other, through a sequence of Reid. moves that temporarily increase the number of crossings.